# MySQL Event Scheduling

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL event scheduled to run everyday at midnight - But the database server is shutdown everyday evening and is restarted every morning, but not necessarily at the same time. For instance the server is started at: 10AM, I still need the event to be executed for the day, though it was scheduled for 12AM. I tested this scenario in ORACLE and it works, but doesn't quite in MySQL. Do you have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Abhilash

Comment: and what code/commands have you written to accomplish this

Comment: Please , Provide your code here.

Answer (score 2):

Direct support for this behaviour was submitted as a feature request in [bug #46813](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46813).  It is still "awaiting triage":

> The event scheduler should be able to periodically check for, and catch up on, missed events. While events that need to run this way can be scheduled using Task Scheduler on Windows and anacron on Mac and *nix, this is inelegant and platform-dependent.

As the bug report suggests, you can schedule such events using software that is external to MySQL.  Alternatively, one could use MySQL's [`init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option%5Fmysqld%5Finit-file) option to specify a file containing commands that should be executed on startup; using that one could check the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events-table.html) table: compare `LAST_EXECUTED` column against event schedule and execute `EVENT_DEFINITION` if a scheduled event was missed.

Comment: Is this feature implemented already? I tested it out using just localhost, and it seems to catch up on missed events. However, I can't see any documentation proving this. Even the link provided here still has a status of 'Verified', when I was expecting it to be 'Closed'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but MySQL doesn't handle this. If the event is missed, it's missed. It doesn't try to run it again later.

What you could do is make a table that logs when an event was last run (the date), then schedule it for each hour, but before running check if it already ran that day. That way the first time it runs after midnight it will activate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event that would fire every hour. Create additional table to store information about event's firing.

Do these steps in the event:

- check if event was fired - read info. from the table
- do the code if the event stil was not fired, write information (the date) into the table.